# Calendar set maxDate to certain day?

Tags: c#, calendar

I'm creating a datetimepicker and I want it to have a maxDate until Saturday every week.
So for example, today is Sunday 16/10/2016, the maximum for this is 22/10/2016. But if i put `maxdate = today + 7` , tuesday maxdate will be monday which I don't want. 
I want to allow the user to be able to choose in 1 week only.
Is this possible ?

Edit:
Sorry,I wrote the wrong thing. It is calendar, not datetimepicker.

Answer (score 2):

DateTime has a DayOfWeek property (that will output the DayOfWeek Monday if it is Monday).  You could pass that property into a helper method that determines the number of days until Saturday based on the current day...

Comment: thanks, this really help me in finding ways to set the first day.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

        int daysToAdd = 6 - (int)today.DayOfWeek;

        DateTime nextSaturday = today.AddDays(daysToAdd);
        Console.WriteLine(nextSaturday.ToShortDateString());
```

Ouputs:
10/22/2016